# Change position of the zero angle of the atan2() or similar

Tags: image-processing, geometry

I have a group of points in an image and I want to order them/get properties in a clockwise direction. The condition to order them will be their angle.

I need to choose the starting point, with angle 0, and then the other points in a clockwise order (increasing angle). However, I am using the atan2 (2 because the range of angles in better) to get the angles, but the zero angle is always in the horizontal axis. How can I set the axis of the zero angle to be in the location of the starting point?

Many thanks!
Hector

Answer (score 2):

If you calculate the starting angle:

```
double theta_0 = atan2(y[0], x[0]);
```

then you can subtract this from subsequent angles and use `fmod` to get the relative angle modulo 2π and thereby get a clockwise positive angle relative to the starting angle:

```
double theta_i = fmod(atan2(y[i], x[i]) - theta_0, M_PI * 2.0);
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. How can I get theta_i in the workspace? If I call it double, it doesn't appear.

Comment: What workspace ? You haven't actually mentioned what programming language or environment you're working with.